# How can i examine all rows in c++?

Tags: c++, max, minimum

You can see my input and output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1p9J.jpg
In the first line 3 means how many line has, and the 5 means how many data has in each line, after that I uploaded the array. In the output i wrote the line id, minimum and maximum data.
My task is that where the minimum data is bigger than the maximum.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

        if(t[i].min > t[i].max)
        {
            cout << t[i].id;
        }
    }
```

But i have this code and it can examine the min and max data line by line. But the correct answer line 3, beacuse in line 3 min data(16) is bigger than line 1 max data(15)

Comment: Nested loops?...

Comment: how? what do you think exatly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood the question correctly you need something like the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    const size_t M = 3, N = 5;
    int a[M][N] =
    {
        { 10, 15, 12, 10, 10 },
        { 11, 11, 11, 11, 20 },
        { 18, 16, 16, 16, 20 }
    };

    std::pair<size_t, size_t> row = { 0, 0 };

    auto p = std::minmax_element( std::begin( a[0] ), std::end( a[0] ) );
    std::pair<int, int> minmax = { *p.first, *p.second };

    for ( size_t i = 1; !( minmax.second < minmax.first ) && ( i < M ); i++ )
    {
        auto p = std::minmax_element( std::begin( a[i] ), std::end( a[i] ) );

        if ( minmax.first < *p.first )
        {
            minmax.first = *p.first;
            row.first = i;
        }

        if ( *p.second < minmax.second )
        {
            minmax.second = *p.second;
            row.second = i;
        }
    }

    if ( minmax.second < minmax.first )
    {
        std::cout << "The minimum " << minmax.first
                  << " in the row " << row.first
                  << " is greater than the maximum " << minmax.second
                  << " in row " << row.second << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The demonstrative program output is

```
The minimum 16 in the row 2 is greater than the maximum 15 in row 0
```

Or in the output statement you can use expressions `row.first + 1` and `row.second + 1` to get the output like

```
The minimum 16 in the row 3 is greater than the maximum 15 in row 1
```

If the program is too complucated to your level of knowledge then here is a simplifed program that uses a user-defined function minmax_element. All you need to know is the standard class std::pair. It is just a class of two elements with names `first` and `second`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

std::pair<size_t, size_t> minmax_element( const int *a, size_t n )
{
    std::pair<size_t, size_t> minmax = { 0, 0 };

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( a[i] < a[minmax.first] ) minmax.first = i;
        else if ( a[minmax.second] < a[i] ) minmax.second = i;
    }

    return minmax;
}

int main() 
{
    const size_t M = 3, N = 5;
    int a[M][N] =
    {
        { 10, 15, 12, 10, 10 },
        { 11, 11, 11, 11, 20 },
        { 18, 16, 16, 16, 20 }
    };

    std::pair<size_t, size_t> row = { 0, 0 };

    auto minmax = minmax_element( a[0], N );

    for ( size_t i = 1; !( a[row.second][minmax.second] < a[row.first][minmax.first] ) && 
                        ( i < M ); i++ )
    {
        auto local_minmax = minmax_element( a[i], N );

        if ( a[row.first][minmax.first] < a[i][local_minmax.first] )
        {
            minmax.first = local_minmax.first;
            row.first = i;
        }

        if ( a[i][local_minmax.second] < a[row.second][minmax.second] )
        {
            minmax.second = local_minmax.second;
            row.second = i;
        }
    }

    if ( a[row.second][minmax.second] < a[row.first][minmax.first] )
    {
        std::cout << "The minimum " << a[row.first][minmax.first]
                  << " in the row " << row.first
                  << " is greater than the maximum " << a[row.second][minmax.second]
                  << " in row " << row.second << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes it's good and work, but this code is too high for me and my teacher, are there any other method for my problem?

Comment: @Awarestor As it was written in comments you can write your own function that finds the minimum and maximum in a row using a for loop.